# Saxon extension: XPath on XdmNode

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Hi I try to implement an extension for saxon in C#. I use the saxon9he interface. The extension itself works fine but now I want to use XPath expressions to get values from a node. I break it down to the relevant code part (the rest is working fine).

The extension has two arguments. The first one is a string, the second one is a node-set.

```
public override IXdmEnumerator Call(IXdmEnumerator[] arguments, DynamicContext context)
{
    if (arguments.Length == 2)
    {
        arguments[0].MoveNext();

        string text = (arguments[0].Current as XdmAtomicValue).Value as string;
        IXdmEnumerator enumerator = arguments[1];

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            XdmNode node = (XdmNode)enumerator.Current;

            // how can I get values from node here by using XPath expressions?
            // e.g. I want the value of the attribute "type" of the subnode "xy"
            // XPath would be something like this: "./xy/@type"

            text = text.Replace(node.NodeName.LocalName, node.StringValue);
        }

        var result = new XdmAtomicValue(text);

        return (IXdmEnumerator)result.GetEnumerator();
    }
    ...
}
```

The 3 comments in the middle show my problem. I want to access subnodes, attributes and so on by XPath expressions. This is a simplified version. The XPath should be passed as an additional argument later. So it is not a fixed XPath expression that I could transform to code. I really need an XPath evaluator.

I saw a solution by creating an XPathEvaluator from a Processor. But I have no Processor at this point, or do I?

Thanks for help.

**Here is the solution (thanks to Michael):**

```
var configuration = context.Implementation.getConfiguration();
var processor = (Processor)configuration.getProcessor();
var xpathCompiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    XdmNode node = (XdmNode)enumerator.Current;

    var keyResult = xpathCompiler.Evaluate(searchXPath, node);
    var valueResult = xpathCompiler.Evaluate(replaceXPath, node);

    string key = "";
    string value = "";

    if (keyResult is XdmAtomicValue)
        key = (string)(keyResult as XdmAtomicValue).Value;
    else if (keyResult is XdmNode)
        key = (string)(keyResult as XdmNode).StringValue;

    if (valueResult is XdmAtomicValue)
        value = (string)(valueResult as XdmAtomicValue).Value;
    else if (valueResult is XdmNode)
        value = (string)(valueResult as XdmNode).StringValue;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || value == null)
        continue;

    text = text.Replace(key, value);
}
```

**Solution for Saxon 9.7:**

The solution above doesn't work for Saxon 9.7 anymore. In this case I pass the processor to the extension classes and from there to the extension call classes at the time I register the extensions.

```
public static void RegisterSaxonExtensions(Saxon.Api.Processor processor)
{
   processor.RegisterExtensionFunction(new MyExtension1(processor));
   processor.RegisterExtensionFunction(new MyExtension2(processor));
}

...

public class MyExtension1 : Saxon.Api.ExtensionFunctionDefinition
{
     private Saxon.Api.Processor processor = null;

     public MyExtension1(Saxon.Api.Processor processor)
     {
         this.processor = processor;
     }

     public override ExtensionFunctionCall MakeFunctionCall()
     {
         return new MyExtension1Call(this.processor);
     }

     ...
}

public class MyExtension1Call : Saxon.Api.ExtensionFunctionCall
{
     private Saxon.Api.Processor processor = null;

     public MyExtension1Call(Saxon.Api.Processor processor)
     {
         this.processor = processor;
     }

     public override IXdmEnumerator Call(IXdmEnumerator[] arguments, DynamicContext context)
     {
         if (arguments.Length == 2)
         {
             arguments[0].MoveNext();

             string text = (arguments[0].Current as XdmAtomicValue).Value as string;
             IXdmEnumerator enumerator = arguments[1];
             var xpathCompiler = this.processor.NewXPathCompiler();

             while (enumerator.MoveNext())
             {
                 XdmNode node = (XdmNode)enumerator.Current;

                 var keyResult = xpathCompiler.Evaluate(searchXPath, node);
                 var valueResult = xpathCompiler.Evaluate(replaceXPath, node);

                 string key = "";
                 string value = "";

                 if (keyResult is XdmAtomicValue)
                     key = (string)(keyResult as XdmAtomicValue).Value;
                 else if (keyResult is XdmNode)
                     key = (string)(keyResult as XdmNode).StringValue;

                 if (valueResult is XdmAtomicValue)
                     value = (string)(valueResult as XdmAtomicValue).Value;
                 else if (valueResult is XdmNode)
                     value = (string)(valueResult as XdmNode).StringValue;

                 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || value == null)
                     continue;

                 text = text.Replace(key, value);
             }

             var result = new XdmAtomicValue(text);

             return (IXdmEnumerator)result.GetEnumerator();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamicContext.Implementation gives you an XPathContext object, this has a getConfiguration() method to get to the Configuration, and the Processor object should be found in Configuration.getProcessor(). From that you should be able to create an XPathEvaluator.

Comment: Hi Michael. I switched from Saxon HE 9.5 to HE 9.7. Now my code fails because `configuration.getProcessor()` now returns a `net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor` instead of a `Saxon.Api.Processor`. I guess the interface is similar but can I work with the classes from the `Saxon.Api` namespace somehow? Or should I adjust the code to use those from the `net.sf.saxon.s9api` namespace?

Comment: If the latter is the case: How can I convert a `Saxon.Api.XdmNode` to a `net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmItem` which the `net.sf.saxon.s9api.XPathCompiler.evaluate` method needs as input? And how can I convert the result of the `evaluate` method (a `net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue`) back to a `Saxon.Api.XdmValue`?

Comment: I suspect this is a side-effect of the fact that in 9.7 we rewrote the Saxon.Api interface on .NET as a thin layer on top of the net.sf.saxon.s9api Java classes. It's not intended that on .NET you should directly use the s9api interfaces in your application. But there's not enough information here to see what's really going on.

Comment: The problem is that `DynamicContext.Implementation` is a `net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext` in 9.7 and there is no `Saxon.Api.XPathContext` anymore like in 9.5. So how could I access a `Saxon.Api.Processor` in 9.7 from within an extension's `Call` method?

Comment: Ok I got it to work by passing the processor down to the extension call classes when creating/registering the extensions.